# Perl perform a pgrep with count line

Tags: perl, count, pipe, ps

I've got a problem using pgrep with the wc command. I find 2 lines where I only expect 1 line.

```
my $test = `pgrep -f 'blabla'`;
print $test;    <------ print the good PID (only one)

my $test = `pgrep -f 'blabla'|/usr/bin/wc -l`;
print $test;  <------- print 2 and a carriage return
```

I find that a carriage return is inserted before the pipe, so wc counts 2 lines.
Is there a way to do a intermediate chomp() beetween the pipe ? 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

`pgrep` is matching itself when you use a pipe. This can be verified if you pipe into `cat` instead of `wc`. You can avoid this by adding in some braces like so, so that the pattern no longer matches itself.

```
my $test = `pgrep -f '[b]labla' | /usr/bin/wc -l`;
```

Comment: Ok I understand the tip. It's curious, the behaviour of bash is different to perl in this case.